# Ionic side menu not showing?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

in my ionic app after login page I have used a side menu.
after login the side menu is showing properly but if I logout and with out refresh Log into the page, the side menu not showing but the menu button is visible.

Button:

```
 <ion-buttons start>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
 </ion-buttons>
```

The Menu Code:

```
<ion-menu>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-navbar color="primary">
          <div class="row">
            <ion-title>HBLOAD</ion-title>
            <button ion-button menuClose>X</button>
          </div>
        </ion-navbar>
        <br>
        <div class="mainbody">
          <button ion-button full (click)="profile()">Profile</button>
          <button ion-button full (click)="changepin()">Change Pin</button>
          <button ion-button full (click)="changepassword()">Change Password</button>
          <button ion-button full (click)="accesslogs()">Access Logs</button>
          <button ion-button full (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
```

Comment: Do you have the opening tag for </ion-menu>?

Comment: yes I have..    I have deleted while I was editing

Comment: ion-menu should be in an ion-app

Comment: did you mean that I should <ion-menu> on app.html file ? if not can you please explain /

Comment: Do you have an ion-nav?

Comment: No. I have used a div to make a nav and put the menu icon there.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the menu would only sometimes appear. try adding #NavContent to that div, and then [content]="NavContent" to the ion-menu. This worked for me, but I was using the ion-nav, worth a shot tho

Comment: ok i will try .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write the code for side menu in the `app.html`file.

And

define the `[content]` attribute in the `<ion-menu>`

**Example:**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content class="nav">

  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your app.component.html, ion-menu should look like this

```
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main">....</ion-menu>
```

and right after *ion-menu* you should define router outlet, which should have an id

```
<ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
```

contentId of *ion-menu* and id of *ion-router-outlet* should be same

Answer (score 1):

For `react` guys that see this someday, here is a tip to programmatically open the side menu

```
import { menuController } from '@ionic/core';

menuController.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

In menu.js file you have to add following code :

```
export default class Menu extends Component {

    render() {
      return(
        <>// **Don't forget to mention this tag**
          
          <IonApp>
      <IonMenu menuId="mainmen" contentId="main">
      
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Menu</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        <IonContent>
          
          <IonList>
          <IonMenuToggle autoHide="false">
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel>Confirm</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
              
              </IonMenuToggle>
          </IonList>
          
        </IonContent>
      
      
   
      </IonMenu>
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main12"></IonRouterOutlet>
    
      </IonApp>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
```

In another page You have import menu.js file and In  you have to mention contentid of contentid of menu. And Add this tag

```
<IonSplitPane contentid ="main">
    <Menu/>

</IonSplitPane>
```

Comment: Here In another Page there is need to mention <Menu/> tag .The above code is for React with ionic